# .htaccess convert nested directory to URL parameter

Tags: .htaccess, url

in .htaccess I want to convert

```
from: website.com/xi/abc

to: website.com/x/?s=abc
```

The user types in website.com/xi/abc
and directory abc doesn't exist, and I just want a nicer looking url where abc is just a parameter, and becomes a parameter for index.html within directory x, parameter name is s, and value abc

The below doesn't quite work. I am trying to make the /abc be just abc and be passed on

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^xi/(.*)$
  RewriteRule ^(.+)$ x/index.html?s=$1 [QSA,L,NE]
```

here is a second attempt which also doesn't work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/xi/(.*)" -f
RewriteRule "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/x/index.html?s=$1" [QSA,L,NE]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I swapped `%{QUERY_STRING}` for `%{REQUEST_URI}` in the `RewriteCond` in order to have the condition satisfied. Then, I prepended the `RewriteRule` matcher with `xi/` in order to filter out that part:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/xi/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^xi/(.+)$ x/index.html?s=$1 [QSA,L,NE]

# http://website.com/xi/abc -> http://website.com/x/index.html?s=abc
# http://website.com/other/abc -> No rewrite
```

In this simple case you can even omit the `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^xi/(.+)$ x/index.html?s=$1 [QSA,L,NE]
```

*Edit*: I used [this .htaccess tester](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/).

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much. That works great.
I was also able to use just x not xi in the original line, I thought maybe same x in original and destination might confuse things, but it's fine, so for my final usage -- RewriteRule ^x/(.+)$ x/index.html?s=$1 [QSA,L,NE]